# Switching measure units in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF UserControl: `MyPage`. 
In MyPage I will let users to add some elements, like images (MyImage) or labels(MyLabel) (inheriting from a WPF `MyPageElement`).

MyPage contains a classical *Grid*, that will contain *MyPageElements*.

Users will be able to modify the elements's *Margin* manually.

When I doubleclick on a element I display a form with element's properties, like `Margin` and `Height`.

Actually, say, a *MyImage*  *Height* is presented in "real units" - pixels WPF.
I'd like to keep the units in "cm" in the DataBase.

Questions

1) Users would like to see the units in "cm"(centimeters) instead of pixels.
Is there a way to "say" so the WPF UserControl to "work" in "cm"?

2) If tomorrow users would like to switch to inches ("in"),
is there a way to dynamically reset the measurements unit?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert units "manually":

"1pt" equals "1.25px" (and therefore 1.25 user units)

"1pc" equals "15px" (and therefore 15 user units)

"1mm" would be "3.543307px" (3.543307 user units)

"1cm" equals "35.43307px" (and therefore 35.43307 user units)

"1in" equals "90px" (and therefore 90 user units)

Comment: Wpf can handle different units by default no need to convert. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx